# Jama Matrix printwriter error

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I am using JAMA matrix in my project. I need to write down a Jama matrix in text file. For that I write down this code.

```
package Xdata;
import Jama.Matrix;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class File_r {
public static void main(String args[]) {


 Matrix A = new Matrix(10, 10);
    try {
        PrintWriter write1 = new PrintWriter(new File("/home/robotics//IdeaProjects/Data_arrange/src/Xdata/mu_X.txt"));
        A.print(PrintWriter write1,9,6);// error in this line
     }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);

        }
    }
}
```

But it throws errors:

```
/home/robotics/IdeaProjects/Data_arrange/src/Xdata/File_r.java
Error:(13, 32) java: ')' expected
Error:(13, 33) java: not a statement
Error:(13, 39) java: ';' expected
```

I wtite down this code in intellj idea. Can any one tell me why I get this error?

Comment: This isn't valid Java - write some valid Java. You wrote `A.print(PrintWriter write1,9,6)`; why not `A.print(PrintWriter write1,int 9,int 6)`? Syntax errors are off topic here.

Comment: @Boris the spider I don't write A.print (PrintWriter write1,int 9,int 6) because Jama matrix documentation did not allow me to do show. They have there own sytax for Print function. This is Java code.This code not look like regular java code because I am using Jama matrix and Jama matrix have some build in function so if I use Jama Matrix I have to use those build in function and there syntax.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense. Java syntax is intransient. No library changes that. You are, I am afraid, confused. My question stands - where in the documentation does it ask you to pass the type of an argument as well as the reference to a method call?

Comment: ~https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/~           from here go to Matrix class then from matrix class go to print   print
public void print(PrintWriter output,
                  int w,
                  int d)
Print the matrix to the output stream. Line the elements up in columns with a Fortran-like 'Fw.d' style format.
Parameters:
output - Output stream.
w - Column width.
d - Number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: Yes, that's a JavaDoc. You dont call [`new PrintWriter(File new File(...))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) do you?

Comment: IF I don't call Printwriter there, then  where should I give the name of classpath and file name where I want to write my jama matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did check the Jama [api](https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html) for Matrix.java. it looks you are trying to use the print method with three parameter in the below snippet . please re-write it correctly.

fix it as below

```
 A.print(write1,9,6);// error in this line
```

Comment: I Already tried in that way,that you suggested here.But it also give me different type of error. Also in jama matrix documention this is suggested.  Thats why I write like this.

Comment: Print is not a class of java. And also a red line appear under write1. When I write Printwriter write1 then a very small red dot appear in between write1 and 9 and this error is give that I already write in my question.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem. I think it is helpful for those who are new to Jama Matrix and face a problem like that. Here is my Solution:

```
package Xdata;
import Jama.Matrix;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

 public class File_r {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Matrix A = new Matrix(10, 10);
    PrintWriter writer=null;
    try {
         writer = new PrintWriter("/home/robotics//IdeaProjects/Data_arrange/src/Xdata/mu_X.txt");// So basically I change this line
        A.print(writer,2,2);
        writer.close();// Add this line

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
  }
}
```

This solve my problem. As there is very less documentation of JAMA Matrix I think this is really help ful for reader.

Comment: It's not a problem with JAMA but with basic java syntax. Not the problem of JAMA documentation.